# Mongoose find data from dynamic Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB  & working on a MEAN application.
In the mongo database(I am using mongoose), the collections are adding dynamically from third party API **like schoolList1,schoolList2,schoolList3,schoolList4,....**

I am facing problem to find a solution to get data from collections, Like If a user sends the argument from FrontEnd to find data from schoolList3.
The find function should apply on that collection only & return the data.

**I am unable to solve it that how should I get data without passing schema and did not get any other way.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [collection name option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) for your schema from user's input:

```
var collectionName = 'schoolList3'; // set value from the input 
var dataSchema = new Schema({/** your schema here **/}, { collection: collectionName });
```